# how to make radio button which select only one option?

Tags: html, css, button, radio-button

when I run this code, its not a radio button like i can click all the 2 button and i cannot remove a click
`<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <title>abc</title> <body> <h1>Input Form</h1> <form action="abc"> <input type="radio">abc <input type="radio">hwqwhdwq </form> </body> </html>`

im a highschool student, imtrying some course in udemy and come accross this problem. I hope someone can help me figure out what im wrong

Comment: _"im a highschool student"_ - not really a sufficient excuse for not going and _reading up_ on how stuff actually works in the first place, IMHO. For example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_ should have already answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
i think you have to do this 
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head>
        <title>abc</title> 
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>Input Form</h1>
        <form action="abc">
            <label for="radio1"><input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radio1"> Radio    1</label>

            <label for="radio2"><input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radio2"> Radio 2</label>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Registration form

Male

```
        <label for="female"><input type="radio" name="Gender" id="radio2" value="female">Female</label>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, I think you're trying to SELECT only one radio checkbox not both right? if yes then this is how to do it, add name="" attribute and set the same name to both of them.

```html
<body>
  <h1>Input Form</h1>
  <form action="abc"> <input type="radio" name="btn">abc <input type="radio" name="btn">hwqwhdwq </form>
</body>
```

Comment: set my answer as the correct one to close the issue